How to make a RTSP connection and manipulating frames
I want to write a app for android to stream, record and save frames on gallery recived from a RTSP connection. I searched for many libs to solve this problem, but i don't find any good one, because either the library didn't provide access to the frames, or I couldn't import it into my project.
I already have tryed this libs for the Kotlin version of project:
https://github.com/pedroSG94/RTSP-Server; - Failed to resolve
https://github.com/pedroSG94/RootEncoder; - Failed to resolve
https://github.com/videolan/vlc-android; - Don't provide access to frames
And this libs for the Java version of project:
https://github.com/androidx/media/tree/main; - Don't makes RTSP connection
https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer/rtsp; - Don't makes RTSP connection
Error output:

E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Playback error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:652)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:624)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.datasource.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rtsp
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:404)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272)
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1006)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rtsp
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:608)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:498)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:447)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:548)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:398)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1006) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
D/ProfileInstaller: Installing profile for com.example.guardiantech

This is my code on Java trying to use androidx to connect to the stream, this is the furthest I got:
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.media3.common.MediaItem;
import androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayer;

import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = this::hideSystemUI;
    private ExoPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).hide();
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        hideSystemUI();

        mMediaPlayer = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

        SurfaceView frameScreen = findViewById(R.id.frameScreen);
        frameScreen.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("my_rtsp_url");
                MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder()
                        .setUri(uri)
                        .setMimeType("video/mpeg")
                        .build();

                mMediaPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.play();
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
                frameScreen.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(width, height));
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                mMediaPlayer.release();
            }
        });

    }

    private void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

        if (hasFocus) {
            mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
            mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, 3000);
        } else {
            mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        }
    }
}


Imports:
def mediaVersion = "1.0.1"
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    // Biblioteca AndroidX Media
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-common:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-session:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:$mediaVersion"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-transformer:$mediaVersion"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

